# how to handle hbase connection closure on spark when worker shuts down in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm, hbase, database-connection

We have a job running on spark cluster, the job need to write to hbase. Since hbase connection is not sharable between nodes, I generate connection for worker to use. Now I have problem with when to close the hbase connection. According to hbase best practice, I should close it myself if I know when the worker ends. However, if the worker is killed by the driver or terminated by any error, will the hbase connection closed automatically? If not, where do I deal with hbase connection in this case. I know the connection leak is not good, but dont know how to avoid it.
Thanks.

Comment: Please try separating your question into shorter, more clear sections. It's a bit hard to read in its current format.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the executor gets killed, it throws a `java.lang.InterruptedException`, which you can catch and close your `HBase` connection gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
    val tableName = TableName.valueOf(tablename)
    val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
    try {
       // Put your HBASE write logic here

    } finally {
      connection.close()     
    }
```